# Why "make all" works as expected without adding "all" to .PHONY target?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I know what a **.PHONY** does.

If in the folder where my Makefile is, I add an empty file called **clean** and after I run make clean all of the clean target will not be executed since there was not any change in the file, so the target will not run and this is correct.
If I add **.PHONY: clean**, than the clean is seen as a command and this is also correct.

My question is why this behavior does not happen the same to **all** target, since I added a **all** file in the folder.So basically the all target still executes like if it was a **.PHONY: all**

I have the fallowing makefile code.

```
all: test1 test2

test1: test1.o
test1.o: test1.c

test2: test2.o
test2.o: test2.c

clean:
        rm -rf *.o test1 test2
```

Comment: It isn't really strictly speaking [needed](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How do you know that the `all` rule is "still executing"?  That rule has no recipe, so there's no way it can be "executed".

If what you mean is that even though the `all` file exists in the local directory, `make` is still building the targets `test1` and `test2`, that's how make works (this doesn't have anything to do with phony vs. non-phony targets).  When make decides whether or not build a particular target first it tries to build all the prerequisites of that target, and all the prerequisites of *those* targets, etc.  Only after all that is complete, can `make` know whether or not to build the first target (`all` in this case).

Answer (score 0):

`make clean` here doesn't have any dependencies, so putting a file named `clean` there is enough for the target to be considered built.

`make all` on the other hand has dependencies. Even if you put a file named `all` there, Make has to check whether the `all` file is newer than `test1` and `test2`. This process triggers builds of `test1` and `test2`, and it happens to have the same effect as if `all` was a phony target.

---

The basis is that `all: test1 test2` is a recipe for building a *file* named `all`, that depends on the *files* `test1` and `test2`.

If you ran `make all`, Make would do something like this:

1. Analyse the `Makefile`.
2. Find out that `all` depends on `test1` and `test2`.
3. Check the timestamp of `all` and see if it is "up to date".

   - It is "up to date" if none of the dependencies are newer than itself.

     - In other words, Make can skip building a file if it's newer than all it's dependencies.
4. Build outdated or missing files.

---

Now, if you would like to prevent Make from considering the targets as files, you could specify them as [phony targets](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html). That is best practice for non-file targets like `all`.

Answer (score 0):

(This answer isn't disagreeing with either of the existing answers, but suggesting another way of thinking about this).

When you have a rule like

```
dst: src
    action
```

you're saying two things (as you know):

1. if `dst` doesn't exist, or is older than `src`, then do `action`; and
2. when `action` completes, the file `dst` will exist.

With targets such as `all` or `clean`, the second statement is of course not true.  Make doesn't hold you to the promise in (2), so when you say `make all`, it'll compute and generate the required dependencies, and not complain that there's no file `all` in place afterwards.  You're lying to Make, but it doesn't mind (it's cool with that...).  That is, this is basically a *makefile hack*.

Where this goes wrong, of course, is if for some reason there happens to be a file called `all` or `clean`.  Then Make will take the modification date of the file `all` into account when calculating the dependencies, and possibly come to a conclusion you didn't expect.

So what `.PHONY: all` does is legitimise the hack, and tells Make ‘even if a file `all` exists, pretend that it doesn't’; you're basically cancelling promise (2).

Therefore, as the other answers state, mentioning `.PHONY` isn't necessary.  It simply forestalls an error – easy to make but easy to miss – when a file matching a phony target is accidentally created.